# phpMyAdmin Error code: 504 with MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am still fairly new to SQL in general. I am trying the following query in phpMyAdmin.

```
SELECT i.`ITEM_NO` as SKU, 
   i.`DESCR` as Description, 
   (SELECT SUM(`QTY_SOLD`) 
           FROM `ps_tkt_hist_lin` 
           WHERE `ITEM_NO` = i.`ITEM_NO` 
              AND `BUS_DAT` >= MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()),1)
              ) as 'QTY Sold YTD',
   (SELECT SUM(`QTY_SOLD`) 
           FROM `ps_tkt_hist_lin` 
           WHERE `ITEM_NO` = i.`ITEM_NO` 
              AND `BUS_DAT` >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL (DAY(CURDATE())-1) DAY), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
              ) as 'QTY Sold Last Month',
   (SELECT SUM(`QTY_ON_HND`) 
           FROM `IM_INV` 
           WHERE `ITEM_NO` = i.`ITEM_NO` 
              AND `LOC_ID` IN ('SL','S','LO','AF')
              ) as 'QTY on Hand'
FROM `ps_tkt_hist_lin` as i
WHERE i.`ITEM_VEND_NO` = 'MD'
GROUP BY i.`ITEM_NO`, i.`DESCR`
ORDER BY i.`ITEM_NO`
```

I get the following error when I run this.

```
Error in processing request
Error code: 504
Error text: Gateway Time-out (rejected)
It seems that the connection to server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status.
```

If it helps, this is the server info:

> Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
>  Server type: MariaDB
>   Server version: 10.1.31-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
>  cpsrvd
>   11.68.0.29
>  Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
>  PHP version: 5.6.30

**Thanks in advance for patiently helping a dude just getting started with SQL and MySQL.**

Comment: How large are your tables?

Comment: The `ps_tkt_hist_lin` table is 195781 rows by 49 columns in size. Should I use another query to get the YTD rows into another table first?

Comment: I suggested an alternative query below.  May not be exactly what you want, but hopefully it will at least not crash your PHP.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I responded to your alternative query. Thank you man.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are seeing could be caused by a handful of different things.  One possibility might be that the tables involved are very large, and the query is just taking too long.  The reason why large tables could be a performance killer is that you have several correlated subqueries in your select clause.

One workaround is to replace the correlated subqueries with appropriate joins to non correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT
    i.ITEM_NO AS SKU,
    i.DESCR AS Description,
    COALESCE(t1.qty_sold_ytd, 0) AS qty_sold_ytd,
    COALESCE(t1.qty_sold_last_month, 0) AS qty_sold_last_month,
    COALESCE(t2.qty_on_hand, 0) AS qty_on_hand
FROM ps_tkt_hist_lin i
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        ITEM_NO,
        SUM(CASE WHEN BUS_DAT >= MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1)
                 THEN QTY_SOLD ELSE 0 END) AS qty_sold_ytd,
        SUM(CASE WHEN BUS_DAT >=
                      DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (DAY(CURDATE())-1) DAY),
                               INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
                 THEN QTY_SOLD ELSE 0 END) AS qty_sold_last_month
    FROM ps_tkt_hist_lin
    GROUP BY ITEM_NO
) t1
    ON i.ITEM_NO = t1.ITEM_NO
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ITEM_NO, SUM(QTY_ON_HND) AS qty_on_hand
    FROM IM_INV
    WHERE LOC_ID IN ('SL','S','LO','AF')
    GROUP BY ITEM_NO
) t2
    ON i.ITEM_NO = t2.ITEM_NO
WHERE
    i.ITEM_VEND_NO = 'MD'
ORDER BY
    i.ITEM_NO;
```

I tried to keep true to the logic of your original query, which did not make complete sense.  For instance, it is not clear why you are aggregating in both the subqueries and outer query.  My suggestion would give you every row from the `ps_tkt_hist_lin` table.

Comment: Hey I appreciate your query here. It did return a handful of errors. Would it help to explain what result I am looking for? I tried the SUMs without the subqueries but it wasn't returning what I was looking for.

Comment: @user1470242 First please reload your page and try the query again.  I was missing some commas in the `SELECT` clause.  If you can get it to run, then you can comment on why it is/is not what you need.

Comment: I got the following `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN QTY_SOLD ELSE 0 END) AS qty_sold_last_month
    FROM ps_tkt_hist_lin
    ' at line 16`

Comment: Sorry again...I miscopied your call to `DATE_SUB`.  It left off part of the expression.  It should work now.

Comment: Hey no problem. I seriously appreciate the help. I got this: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTEVAL 1 MONTH)
                 THEN QTY_SOLD ELSE 0 END) AS qty_sold_last_mo' at line 16`

Comment: Obviously it's supposed to be `INTERVAL`.

Comment: <Forehead Slap> Sorry I saw it right after commenting. So it timed out still. I am wondering if I should do another query first that only brings over some of the data to another table that I can then query.

Comment: You now have multiple problems.  You can't get _any_ query to run on PHP, and also you are not sure if the query would even return the right results.  My advice to you is to pick one problem, and focus on that.  By now, this thread is abandoned, so you will probably need to open a new question.  I'm out for now, good luck.